# MYSQL - If first field is not null, then update second field, if second field is not null, then etc

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql question here. What I'm trying to do is create a button ('Add to Wishlist') that, when pressed, executes a MYSQL update query that enters a number, say 6, into multiple fields, however I'm trying to get is so that it only enters in one field that is not null. So in essence, the update query will look to see if field one (saved_courses) is empty, and if it is then insert value, but if it isn't then insert into the second field (saved_courses2).

I've looked into this and as a result of my research I have this:

```
   mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE  user_accounts SET saved_courses3 = case when  saved_courses3 is null then saved_courses3 = $urlid else saved_courses4 = $urlid end WHERE id = 1; ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I recommend, to normalize your db's structure. Create a table called `saved_couses` with at least two fields `user_id`, `course_id`. It will be much more maintainable. (How will you 'delete' the 4th saved course from the current structure? What happens when the 6 slots are not enough?)

Comment: @Pred Regarding the table structure, since the user is going to be saving multiple course ID's to his/her account, how would I create a table that would allow the user to do such thing? I was planning on making multiple fields: saved_course1, saved_course2 etc

Comment: The recommended structure is in my previous comment, but this is another question. It is unfortunate to discuss it in the comments section. Either try to read more about `normalization` and `normal forms` to get the idea, or post a new question. (recommendation: read more, than if you are not sure, or you do not understand something, and you do not found the answere, post a new question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE  user_accounts SET 
saved_courses4 = case when saved_courses3 is null then saved_courses4 else $urlid end, 
saved_courses3 = case when saved_courses3 is null then $urlid else saved_courses3 end
WHERE id = 1
```

You can see it in action at:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5553/1